# SqlCeUpdatableRecord setDatetime convert '2079'

Tags: c#, sql, compact-framework

In the sql database i have a smalldatetime record '1.1.2079'. Now I want to insert this record into a sql compact datetime record. I'm using `SqlCeUpdatableRecord` and `SetDateTime`

```
rec.SetDateTime(i, Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDataReader[columnName].ToString()));
```

But i get in the compact database the record as '1.1.1979'.
I don't get it why. Can please tell me how to get '1.1.2079' in the compact version also.

Comment: Why are you converting the value to a string and then parsing it? What is the value in `sqlDataReader[columnName]`, exactly? (Look at it in the debugger.)

Comment: Is the record really smalldatetime? If so, why are you using ToString then parsing?

Comment: you are right! This was the problem, i fix it! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
rec.SetDateTime(i, Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDataReader[columnName]));
```

There is no need to convert `.ToString()` the value from `sqlDataReader`.